# template literals inside the javascript object [es6]

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

how can i assign object value to other key of object. I tried this but it is not working all i get is undefined.

```
let test = {
 id:1,
 name:this.test.id
}

let test2 = {
 id:1,
 name:`hello, ${this.id}`
}

console.log(test)
console.log(test2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the object `this` is the context in which the object is created, and not object itself (since it doesn't exist yet). Use a getter to compute the value.

```js
let test = {
 id:1,
 get name() { return this.id }
}

let test2 = {
 id:1,
 get name() { return `hello, ${this.id}` }
}

console.log(test)
console.log(test2);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).